# Python code to create playlist from multiple folders

Tags: python, kodi

This is my first ever question on Stack Overflow, I am terribly sorry if this has been repeated. I have been searching for the last month or so for some code, to create a random playlist that would run each night on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) using Python. But have had no luck!

The playlist would be made up of content from 2 folders. Music in 1 (about 200 files) Ads/Jingles (5 files) in the other. I want to be able to create a playlist (m3u format) that would randomize the music each day but still have an ad/jingle playing every 5 songs. So the only thing that should repeat each day is the ads/jingles.

I am currently running Kodi for the music player, as I want movies as well.

Is there anyone that would be able to help me with this?

Comment: You're probably going to need to show some attempts at this to get someone to help you. You may want to look here for how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others wanting to do this, I found a good way around it using bash. Got this from: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=63568

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /home/pi/music.lock ]; then
echo "Lock Exists, exiting"
exit 0
fi
touch /home/pi/music.lock
target="21"
cur=$(date '+%H')
while [ $target != $cur ]
do
cd /home/pi/music
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
cd /home/pi/messages
mpg321 "$(ls *.mp3 | shuf -n1)"
cur=$(date '+%H')
done
rm /home/pi/music.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps a little. Not too sure on the music player. I assume you have a method to open up the file and play it. The list of files denoted in today's playlist can be iterated on as needed.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
music_file_path = "music"
jingle_file_path = "ads/jingles"
jingle_files = [ f for f in listdir(music_file_path) if isfile(join(music_file_path,f)) ]
music_files = [ f for f in listdir(jingle_files) if isfile(join(jingle_files,f)) ]

music_files.shuffle()
jingle_files.shuffle()

todays_playlist = []
for i in range(len(music_files)):
    todays_playlist.append(music_files[i])
    if i % 5 == 0:
        todays_play_list.append(jingle_files[ (i // 5) % len(jingle_files)])
```

Comment: I would also add that (1) `m3u` files have relatively simple format (see Wikipedia), so it shouldn't be a problem to create it now. (2) Universal approach to open a file in associated application in Python is `import webbrowser; webbrouser.open(fname)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Unfortunately the code didn't work, I am extremely new to Python so I am terribly sorry if this is a common problem. I receive an error at music_files =

TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly.